# Ubuntu virtual machine routing problem

Tags: linux, routing

Defining the problem is a little bit complicated. So İ will attempt to draw the case:
[image]

Number 2 is an ubuntu router(virtual box Vm) with three interfaces. Number 1 is a emulated router, and the number 3 is a remote host behind some routers. When İ ping number-3 from number-1, ping request goes thru 'a' and 'c' path, but reply comes from 'b' path. İn this case number-2 does not route ping reply to number-1, so ping fails. But if ping reply comes from 'c' path, then number-2 routes the reply packet. What is the problem with the first case??

Comment: Does the packet has the correct IP?  Is there a NAT in this scenario?

Comment: Also, are there any firewalls in the way?

Comment: Yes, when i check the packets in  either case with tcpdump, ips were right, no NAT and no firewall..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to what Linux calls [reverse path filtering](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?id=refs/tags/v4.6#n1077) (see also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_path_forwarding)).

Basically if traffic comes from a host on an interface which traffic to the host would not use, the kernel drops the traffic.

Fixing it is simple

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.$iface_b.rp_filter=2
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.$iface_c.rp_filter=2
```

Replace `$iface_b` and `$iface_c` with the appropriate interface names.

*(on older kernels `2` may be unavailable, so use `0`)*

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for.  Thanks..